# How to parse xml to Json ionic 2

Tags: json, xml, angular, ionic2

I have been on this problem for the past three days. I want to convert an XML which is retrieved via HTTP into JSON so I can display it in ionic 2. Here is my codes in a provider.. Any help will be much appreciated.. thank you!

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import * as xml2js from "xml2js";


@Injectable()
export class News {

    constructor(public http: Http) { }

    public getData() {

        this
            .http
            .get('https://www.ug.edu.gh/news.xml')
            .map(res => {

                var cleanedString = res.toString().replace("\ufeff", "");

                xml2js
                .parseString(cleanedString, (error, result) => {

                    console.log(result);
                    return result;

                });

            })
            .subscribe((data) => {
                console.log(data)
            }, (err) => {
                console.log(err)
            });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Parsing xml to json in ionic 2 
You can install the typings for xml2json now using the command

```
typings install xml2json --save
```

If it generate error like this

```
'typings' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file.
```

Then first use this command to install typing

```
npm install typings -g
```

Then run previous command

```
typings install xml2json --save
```

Then it'll work fine.
Hope it work for you

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. Things go wrong when you `return` the data from `parseString` method. You just should use a temporary variable, assign the result from the `parseString` method and return that temporary variable like so:

```js
// ...
.map(res => {

    let cleanedString = res.toString().replace("\ufeff", "");
    let jsonData;

    xml2js
    .parseString(cleanedString, (error, result) => {

        if(error) {
            console.error(error);
            jsonData = error;
        } else {
            jsonData = result;
        }

    });

    return jsonData;

}).subscribe((data) => {
// ...
```

A more in depth description and an alternative method is given [here.](https://www.ionicrun.com/transform-xml-to-json-in-ionic-2-with-angular-4-3/)